# How to check whether if a particular email has been replied

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook

Consider I have 5 mails in my inbox and want to check which emails has been replied by User.

Note:

1. It may happen out of those 5 emails, 2 emails has been the reply of one email
2. It may also happen One user has edited the 'Re' from email subject.
3. It may be a read/unread message

I was able to fetch email from the outlook folder, but was unable to verify whether the email is a reply or not by Team members.

```
import win32com. client.
outlook=win32com. client. Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
inbox=outlook. GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages=inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    print (message.Subject)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be covered in the documentation?

Comment: @AMC Sorry, didn't get you

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter items based on the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` property (DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003`) which contains the last verb executed - replied, forwarded and etc.

Use the `PropertyAccessor` object from the Outlook object model to get the property value:

```
lastVerbExecuted = vItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
```

Also, instead of iterating over all items in the folder, I'd recommend using the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods where you can get only items that correspond to your conditions. For example, you may get all items that have the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` property set using the following search criteria:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003 is not null
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Get unread Outlook e-mail items from the Inbox folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/27/outlook-get-unread-items/)